# How to combine multiple density plots in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to combine multiple density plots into a single density plot and there are overlapping area among them.

I have tried but what I got is like the figure below.
It seems that the density plot is just on the top of the other plots.

[image]

What I want is that the overlapping areas are combined. 
Then, a single density plot is made.

Here is my code.

```
#import libraries
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

plt.figure()
ax=plt.gca()
ax.set_ylim([-5,5]);
ax.set_xlim([-5,5]);

def Z(x1,y1,n):
    x      = np.linspace(-5, 5, 1000)
    X, Y   = np.meshgrid(x, x)
    Z1     = np.sin(n * X) * np.cos(n * Y)
    mask   = (X - x1) ** 2 + (Y - y1) ** 2 > 1
    Z1     = ma.masked_where(mask, Z1)
    plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z1, cmap='rainbow')

Z(0,-1,1)
Z(0,0,2)
Z(0,1,1)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you considered combining the three sets of data being plotted into a single data set? That seems to be the most straightforward approach

Comment: Any time you’re plotting something in matplotlib you are plotting a set of data - the fact that this is data generated from functions that you are trying to represent makes no difference. When I say combine the datasets I mean create one single array for each `X`, `Y`, and `Z` which contains the data generated from *all* the functions, instead of overwriting the arrays as you are doing here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did another attempt.
It seems it is working.

```
#import libraries
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

plt.figure()
ax=plt.gca()
ax.set_ylim([-5,5]);
ax.set_xlim([-5,5]);

x      = np.linspace(-5, 5, 1000)
X2, Y2   = np.meshgrid(x, x)

def Z(x1,y1,n):
    Z1     = np.sin(n * X2) * np.cos(n * Y2)
    Z1     = np.where((X2 - x1) ** 2 + (Y2 - y1) ** 2 > 1, 0, Z1)
    return Z1

def mask(x1,y1):
    mask = (X2 - x1) ** 2 + (Y2 - y1) ** 2 > 1
    return mask


ZZ = Z(0,-1,1) +  Z(0,0,2) + Z(0,1,1)

mask = mask(0,-1) & mask(0,0) & mask(0,1)
ZZ = ma.masked_where(mask, ZZ)

plt.pcolormesh(X2, Y2, ZZ, cmap='rainbow')


plt.show()
```

Here is the result.
Any comments are welcome.

[image]